# STM32 USB Dongle ST-utility connection problem

Tags: stm32, programming, hardware, swd

I'm using a [CANADUINO ST-Link V2 USB Dongle](https://www.amazon.ca/CANADUINO-Compatible-Circuit-Programmer-Debugger/dp/B07B2K6ZPK/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=stlink&qid=1681595705&s=electronics&sr=1-2) (SWD).

I'm trying to connect to the chip but I keep getting this error:
[image]

I do have the reset pin attached to the USB.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem is we can't know what you connected and how. Also, that's not an original ST-Link, but what is weird that clone still costs almost as much as the real thing instead of $5. So don't expect clone products to work as well as original.

Comment: You need to provide additional information: schematics, SWD settings, what you've done so far, etc.